# Circular array won't rotate properly

Tags: modifiers

I want to make the wedge object create a circular array around the wheel but instead it spirals off to the centre and changes the size of each new wedge.

I have the wedge's center set to the 3d cursor.

Any ideas?? :)

[image]

Comment: apply your scale

Comment: @Chris I think that you can give it as an answer (apply the empty scale)

Comment: @moonboots : but you need the points - or you will beat Gandalf in 2049…but you want to beat him earlier, right? 

Comment: yes but you'll need to beat me in 2300